# Como capturar conteúdo de site e armazenar em um banco de dados

Tags: php, java, string, file-get-contents

[Aqui](http://www.maringa.com/empregos/) o site que possui as vagas

> Se puderem entrem nele e vejam como funciona.

Eu preciso pegar os títulos das vagas e as descrições que contem neles como a: *Empresa, Área de atuação e Requisitos*.

Minha dúvida é como faço para pegar essas informações e armazenar elas dentro de um Banco de Dados?

Reparem que tem que **clicar** na vaga para ter acesso a descrição dela, e ao abrir a janela que mostra informações, o conteúdo não pode ser copiado, mesmo não tem como selecionar o texto!

Comment: Webcrawler e webscraper são termos relacionados ao tipo de programa que vc quer fazer. Estou mencionando pq em muitos casos saber o nome das coisas faz muita diferença na pesquisa.

Comment: Olá, Felipe. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Esta pergunta é um pouco ampla, envolve muita coisa e tem infinitas possibilidades de resposta. Eu diria que você precisa dividir o problema em partes: primeiro você deve identificar como acessar as informações, depois como transformar numa estrutura de dados no seu programa, depois como isso será armazenado e com qual tecnologia. Cada um desses pontos tem inúmeras possibilidades de solução que dependem do contexto. Aliás, a primeira pergunta deve ser: você tem direitos de acessar e usar a informação que vai colher do site da forma como pretende?